# Append two mutable lists

Tags: racket

I want to write `append!`.

For example: if I have

```
(define ml1 (mlist 1 2 3))
(define ml2 (mlist 4 5 6))
ml1
ml2

'#&(#&1 . #&(#&2 . #&(#&3 . #&())))
'#&(#&4 . #&(#&5 . #&(#&6 . #&())))
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
(append! ml1 ml2)
(mlist->list ml1)
;; produces '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "give me the codez" site. What have you tried?

Comment: @WillNess In Racket immutability is the default for lists. Thus `list` returns an immutable list. To get a mutable list one must use `mlist`. In short all (almost) list operations come in two flavors. The ones working on mutable lists usually have a name that beings with `m`.

Comment: @soegaard thanks! (too bad OP was reckless with their tag usage...)

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation on [mappend!](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html?q=mappend!#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/mpair..rkt%29._mappend!%29%29)

```
(require racket/mpair)
(mappend! ml1 ml2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic strategy will be to get to the end of the first list via repeated calls to `mcdr`, and then use `set-mcdr!` to set the last cons cell of the first list to the head of the second list.

For instance, using your definitions, this should work to append `ml2` to `ml1`

```
(set-mcdr! (mcdr (mcdr ml1)) ml2)
(mlist->list m1) ; => '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Now all you have to do is turn it into a function for arbitrary sized mlists and account for empty lists being passed in and what-not.